# Consolidate values of a row into a cell and repeating the process down a column using a single formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a column, I want to consolidate all the values in a row separated by the top or top-left-most column header name. I want the formula to be a single column formula that process down a column or up to row 500. In Google Sheets, this would utilize an ArrayFormula, but since this is Excel, I don't know how to process this solution as a single formula without having to drag down/fill down or use custom table.

See image below and I will [link to the sheet here.](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ApYx4AGhwQsDj0LdrGN5XFx1W2xj?e=FeX3xJ)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Join Data

```
=LET(table,E4:M8,IgnoreNoCat,1,ShowNoMatch,0,
        hDel,CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),hdDel,CHAR(10),dcDel,", ",
    hd,TAKE(table,1),dd,DROP(table,1),
    h,SCAN("",hd,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v<>"",v,a))),
    hu,UNIQUE(h,1),
    br,BYROW(dd,LAMBDA(r,LET(
        bc,BYCOL(hu,LAMBDA(c,LET(
            jd,TEXTJOIN(dcDel,IgnoreNoCat,FILTER(r,h=c)),
        IF(LEN(jd)=0,IF(ShowNoMatch,c,""),c&hdDel&jd)))),
    TEXTJOIN(hDel,,bc)))),
br)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow this works! Is it possible to combine the formula with the header name and place it in Cell C4? I understand in Google Sheets it would look something like "={"Headername"; yourFormulaHere}" but not sure how to do it in Excel.