# Consolidate values of a row into a cell and repeating the process down a column using a single array formula

Tags: google-sheets

In a column, I want to consolidate all the values in a row separated by the top or top-left-most column header name. The formula needs to be an array formula (no drag-filling). The formula needs to be written in such a way that new columns can be inserted, and headers can be added in between the "Begin Range" and the "End Range".

See image below for desired behavior. I am also linking to the sheet [here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_m_QVa3afpfKJ0Wthmn8IacrVSrgG4eRtwjDTLPOW58/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

As a reference, there is a tab in the linked sheet for the Excel version of the solution. The Excel solution is from the accepted answer in this [stack post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76878449/consolidate-values-of-a-row-into-a-cell-and-repeating-the-process-down-a-column/76881082#76881082)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
=LET(header,E4:M4,
     data,E5:M,
     n,CHAR(10),
    _header,SCAN(,header,LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c="",a,c))),
    BYROW(data,LAMBDA(_data,IF(COUNTA(_data)=0,,
      TEXTJOIN(n&n,1,MAP(UNIQUE(_header,1),LAMBDA(cat,
        LET(f,FILTER(_data,_header=cat),
            IF(COUNTA(f)=0,,cat&n&TEXTJOIN(n,1,f))))))))))
```